# Horizontal ListView in a Widget

Tags: android, listview, widget, horizontalscrollview

I am making a **`widget`** for my application. It currently has a regular `ListView` which scrolls **vertically**. What I want is that it should scroll **Horizontally**.

As Widgets don't support any **customViews**, I can't use any libraries.

Also, as widgets don't support **`RecyclerViews`** I can't use them either.

How do I get a **horizontally** scrolling list in a **`Widget`**?

Comment: You should use recyclerview for horizontal scrolling. Use this gradle link to use recyclerview com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1

Comment: Do widgets support recyclerViews?

Comment: Here is a list of the supported views in a widget. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: Then you should use custom library for horizontal listview

Comment: " However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget. " - From Android Docs. Widgets don't support CustomViews.

Comment: Please View the link I have shared above ^^